# Sequences of RVs have equal finite-dimensional distribution, then the "supremum" processes have equal finite-dimensional distributions??

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Say $(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ and $(Y_{1},...,Y_{n})$ have the same finite dimensional distributions, can I say that for any $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$,

$$ P(\overline{X_{n}}\in A)=P(\overline{Y_{n}}\in A)$$ where $$\overline{X_{n}}:= \sup\limits_{j=1,...,n}X_{j}\text{  and   }\;\overline{Y_{n}}:= \sup\limits_{j=1,...,n}Y_{j}$$.

My idea: Consider the generating set of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$, namely, $\{ (-\infty,x]: x \in \mathbb R\}$. Then for $x\in \mathbb R$, we have:

$$ P(\overline{X_{n}}\in (-\infty,x])=P(\cap_{j\in [n]}\{{X_{j}}\in (-\infty,x]\})=P(\cap_{j\in [n]}\{{Y_{j}}\in (-\infty,x]\})=P(\overline{Y_{n}}\in (-\infty,x]).$$

We then use the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem to extend the result to the entire sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$. Is this approach correct?

Additional question: Can I indeed say that the vectors $(\overline{X_{1}},...,\overline{X_{n}})$ and $(\overline{Y_{1}},...,\overline{Y_{n}})$ have the same finite-dimensional distributions?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.
There is

**lemma**: if $\mathcal{\pi}$ is $\pi$-sistem of subsets of $\Omega$ then two measures are equal on $\mathcal{\pi}$ iff they are equal on $\sigma(\mathcal{\pi})$.
To prove this lemma we may use $\lambda$-systems.

Hence two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with Borel sigma-algebra are equal iff they are equal on $(-\infty, x]$ for every $x$.

Hence the first statement is true.

Notice that instead of $\sup$ it's more natural to work with $\max$.

As $Z_1 = (\overline{X}_1, \overline{X}_2, \ldots, \overline{X}_n ) = h(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $Z_2 = (\overline{Y}_1, \overline{Y}_2, \ldots, \overline{Y}_n ) = h(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ it follows that
$$P(Z_1 \in B) = P(h(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in B) = P( (X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in h^{-1}B )$$
$$ =P( (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \in h^{-1}B ) =  P(h(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \in B) = P(Z_2 \in B) $$
for all Borel $B$.

It follows that second statement is true.

Comment: Can I be sure that $h$ as you have defined is a measurable transformation?